# how to access static member variables in complex inheritance

Tags: c++

I have a problem like below:

```
class base
{
public:
    base() {}
};

class A : public base
{
public:
    A() {}

    void dosomething()
    {
        // here I want to access the static var created inside class B
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    B() {}

private:
    A base;
    static int var;
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    return 0;
}
```

I like to get access to that `static var` inside `dosomething()` function.

I do not like to pass it through constructor arguments, I am looking to solve thing by using functions or direct access.
I know how to access in simple inheritance, but this is like reverse case, which I do not know.

Comment: Write a `static` getter function for it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ok let me check how to do that.

Comment: Are you sure you want to call the class-A member of class B by the name "base"? That's very confusing.

Comment: Inheritance is irrelevant here. You simply want to access a static member of a different class, which you can do if it's `public`.

Comment: @einpoklum as I mentioned, I can change the structure and solve the problem. But I would like to know if anyone has an idea to solve this when the structure is like as shown.

Comment: @14yearoldprogrammer You might be interested in _static polymorphism_ as provided with the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Answer (score -1):

First of all, the `static int var;` is `private`, hence no other class (apart from `B`) can access it. So, solutions to that are: making it `public`, implementing getter/setter methods for it, or marking `class A` as a friend of `class B`.

Second of all, this problem is solved simply by splitting your `class`es into header, and implementation files.

> Base.h

```
#ifndef BASE__H
#define BASE__H
class base
{
public:
    base() {}
};
#endif
```

> A.h

```
#ifndef A__H
#define A__H
#include "base.h"
class A : public base
{
public:
    A() {}
    void dosomething();
};
#endif
```

> B.h

```
#ifndef B__H
#define B__H
#include "A.h"
class B
{
public:
    B() {}

private:
    A base;
    static int var;

friend class A;
};
#endif
```

> A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
void A::dosomething()
    {
    B::var = 42;
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

Add an static public member function to B to access var and access it wherever required.

```
class base
{
public:
    base() {}
};
class B
{
public:
    B() {}
    static void setVar(int value) { var = value; }
    static int getVar() { return var; }
private:
    static int var;
};
class A : public base
{
public:
    A() {}

    int dosomething()
    {
        return B::getVar();
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    return 0;
}
```

This above solution compiles successfully.
There are four combinations of (shared, accessible) pairs. 
- `public static` variable is shared and accessible outside the class
- `private static` variable is shared, but not accessible outside the class
- `public` non-static variable is not shared, but accessible outside the class
- `private` non-static variable is neither shared nor accessible outside the class

Note that the way you deal with the private static `value` can be modeled after the way you work with non-static `val`, i.e. by giving your class users some public member-functions to work with the static variable:

```
class Sample {
...
public:
    static int getvalue() { return value; }
};
```

Now you can print it like this:

```
cout << "static value = " << Sample::getvalue();
```

Comment: I'm very sure this won't compile.

Comment: This will compile Give a try.